# Segmentation fault with strcmp (lists)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a list, and I want to remove registers from this list comparing people's names.
Here is the function remove:

```
void remove(char name[]){
  if (pBegin!=NULL){
    Nodo *pcopy;
    if (!strcmp(name,pBegin->person.name)){
      pcopy=pBegin;
      pBegin=pBegin->pNext;
      printf("REMOVED!\n");
      free(pcopy);
    }
    else{
      Nodo *pCurrent=pBegin;
      Nodo *pPrevious=NULL;
      while ((strcmp(name,pCurrent->person.name)) && (pCurrent!=NULL)){  // here is probably the error
        pPrevious=pCurrent;
        pCurrent=pCurrent->pNext;
      }
      if (pBegin==NULL)
        printf("The name was not found!\n");
      else{
        pPrevious->pNext=pCurrent->pNext;
        printf("REMOVED!\n");
        free(pCurrent);
      }
    }
  }
  else
    printf("empty list!\n");
}
```

Sorry for the big post and visually ugly. It is my first post here and I'm new to C, have tried everything but can not solve this error.

Comment: There is far too much code there for us to dig through. Please debug your program and if you can't fix it, post a question with a short example demonstration the issue. StackOverflow is not a debugging service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too late testing pCurrent!=NULL after you've used it in strcmp.

```
   while (pCurrent!=NULL && strcmp(name,pCurrent->person.name)){ // test names are different
```

Comment: thank you, the program is working correctly now :-)